# Screen going automatically on after shotting down

Tags: screen

I have a problem and did not found any help til now.

I'm running on Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS on an Thinkpad Edge E320 with 128 GB SSD and 8GB RAM and occure following issue: when my screen shots of after the set 1 min, it goes automatically on after 5-10 min. It stays on for 1 min, than shots of an than again, 5 -10 min later it  goes on again without even beeing near the device. 
It is a configuration issue I think, but where and waht can I configure?
Thanks for any help!﻿

Comment: Ok, so meanwhile I made a fresh install and the problem doesn't comes up anymore. If someone has an idea, what it have my be caused it, I would appriciate to leav a comment here. Thanks!